# What does "consume an API" mean?

Tags: api, rest, backbone.js

Here is an excerpt from an assignment I am currently doing:

> Build a dummy app that:
>
> - Contains a REST API that operates over a single resource.
> - Contains a Backbone client that consumes that API and can list, show, create, update, and remove that resource.

My understanding was that the term "consume" implies total coverage of the API's exposed ressources. However, the assignment says "consumes that API **and** can [CRUD] that resource".

Is that sentence redundant or is my understanding of the term wrong?

(Bonus question: why searching Google for this question returns countless language-specific tutorials for "consuming an API" but none explain what the term actually means?).

Comment: Consume just means use some method of the API. It doesn't mean "use all the methods".

Comment: For a discussion see:- https://medium.com/@renzo.cordova.d/why-do-developers-use-the-word-consume-6d0912cbf8b2

Answer (score 59, accepted):

To consume an API means to basically use any part of it from your application.

Comment: You get the check since you were first to reply. So basically, "consume an API" is just a fancy term for "use an API". I don't know if I should be relieved or disappointed...

Comment: @gabriels The whole IT field is filled with fancy and buzz words, that often are thrown there by people who barely understand what they mean.

Answer (score 10):

Consuming an API here means creating a client which can send requests to the API that you build.

It appears that you need to create and API which can handle Create, retrieve, update and delete (CRUD) of a resource.  For instance if your REST api is to create a blog, your API should handle CRUD functions for the object/resource blogpost. 
POST - Create a blog post
GET - Retrieve a blog post
PUT - Update a blog post
DELETE - Delete a blog post.

Answer (score 7):

It is about the direction of the app's interaction with API - it either provides an API, or consumes it, so there are providers and consumers of API, and this is just a less general and ambiguous term than 'using'.

Answer (score 2):

Simply consuming an API means using it in your application.

For, e.g., `GET` request to `https://someapi/Users` will give you all the users.

You need to request this URL `https://someapi/Users` to get all the users and then you can use it into your application.

Answer (score 2):

I always think about Albert Einstein's quote of "If you can’t explain it to a six year old, you don’t understand it yourself." when someone asks a question that you might take for granted due to technical experience you have on a subject.

I think the following medium.com article does an excellent job explaining it: [How do you explain API to a 5-year-old?](https://geetima.medium.com/how-do-you-explain-api-to-a-5-year-old-7d70f6986a15)

Answer (score 1):

simply means : using the API.

You can do it with HTTP method (GET, POST, PUT, DELETE..) using something like `Postman` (Tool) or maybe you have a client `app/library` that calls these methods implicitly.