# What does it mean to say 'API should be implemented which is consuming and producing “application/json”'?

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest, intellij-idea, backend

I am aware what an API is but I do not actually understand what it means when we say consumes or produces application/json in the context of a REST API. I have found several sources explaining how to do it but not what it actually is. I am using Java with SpringBoot in IntelliJ, so any examples relevant to that would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: So which part of it do you not understand: the produce/consume part, or the application/json part? Actually, take a step back first: in your own words, what **is** an API, and how do you use it? Also, please read [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592).

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24661302/ answer your question? I found it by copying and pasting your question title into a search engine.

Comment: The duplink is slightly different in that it is asking about "consuming an API" versus an "API that consumes something".  But the meaning of the words "produce" and "consume" are (respectively) almost identical in the two contexts.  (Looking them up in an English dictionary would probably help you too.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd like to explain what consume means, it means if you send a POST request with JSON as the content type, your service should be able to accept it and doesn't reject it.

The service sample code is here:

```java
import com.fishpro.restcontroller.domain.UserDO;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("user2")
public class UserRestController {

    @PostMapping("/update")
    @ResponseBody
    public Object update(@RequestBody User user){
        Map<String,Object> map=new HashMap<>();
        if(null==user){

            map.put("status",3);
            map.put("message","Empty Content");
            return  map;
        }
        //更新逻辑
        map.put("status",0);
        return  map;
    }
}

// The entity class
public class User {
    private Integer userId;
    private String userName;

    public Integer getUserId() {
        return userId;
    }

    public void setUserId(Integer userId) {
        this.userId = userId;
    }

    public String getUserName() {
        return userName;
    }

    public void setUserName(String userName) {
        this.userName = userName;
    }
}
```

Let's take look at an example(you can use IDEA HTTP Client to execute it https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2022.3/http-client-in-product-code-editor.html#open-requests-collection ) :

Do post to a Restful Service:

POST http://localhost:8087/user2/update, the request:

```
POST /user2/update HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/json
Host: localhost:8087

{
  "userId": 1,
  "userName": "userName_txxhs"
}
```

And the response:

```http
HTTP/1.1 200 
Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Date: Fri, 13 Jan 2023 04:09:57 GMT

{"status":0}
```

It works because the HTTP client sends the correct content type and the server accepts it and produces the right one.

So in case we change the service annotation and force the client to use another Content-Type: application/text:

```
// ...
    @PostMapping(value="/update", consumes = {"application/text"}, produces = {"application/json"})
    @ResponseBody
    public Object update(@ModelAttribute User user){
// ...
```

Then the response will say that it can't consume (support) this content type:

```http
HTTP/1.1 415
Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Date: Fri, 13 Jan 2023 04:41:46 GMT
Connection: close

{"timestamp":"2023-01-13T04:41:46.278+0000","status":415,"error":"Unsupported Media Type","message":"Content type 'application/json' not supported","path":"/user2/update"}
```

So the request has to change the `content type` and then the response will work:

```http
POST /user2/update HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/text
Host: localhost:8087
Connection: close
User-Agent: RapidAPI/4.1.1 (Macintosh; OS X/13.1.0) GCDHTTPRequest
Content-Length: 50

{
  "userId": 1,
  "userName": "userName_txxhs"
}
```

It's much simple for the annotation `produces`,  just simply change the `Content-Type` header of the response, and yes that your Spring boot application should provide logic to convert any object to that content type.

I hope this will help you to understand it, and you may find the HTTP resources and specifications helpful:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Resources_and_specifications